# Difference between numpy var() and pandas var()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics

I recently encountered a thing which made me notice that `numpy.var()` and `pandas.DataFrame.var()` or `pandas.Series.var()` are giving different values. I want to know if there is any difference between them or not?

Here is my dataset.

```py
     Country    GDP     Area    Continent
0      India    2.79    3.287   Asia
1      USA     20.54    9.840   North America
2      China    13.61   9.590   Asia
```

Here is my code:

```py
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

ss = StandardScaler()

catDf.iloc[:,1:-1] = ss.fit_transform(catDf.iloc[:,1:-1])
```

Now checking Pandas Variance

```
# Pandas Variance
print(catDf.var())
print(catDf.iloc[:,1:-1].var())
print(catDf.iloc[:,1].var())
print(catDf.iloc[:,2].var())
```

The output is

```
GDP     1.5
Area    1.5
dtype: float64
GDP     1.5
Area    1.5
dtype: float64
1.5000000000000002
1.5000000000000002
```

Whereas it should be 1 as I have used StandardScaler on it.

And for numpy Variance

```
print(catDf.iloc[:,1:-1].values.var())
print(catDf.iloc[:,1].values.var())
print(catDf.iloc[:,2].values.var())
```

THe output is

```
1.0000000000000002
1.0000000000000002
1.0000000000000002
```

Which seems correct.

Comment: [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html) var has `ddof` of `1` by default, [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) has it at `0`. Try `catDf.iloc[:,1:-1].var(ddof=0)`.

Comment: Yes it works. Write an answer for it, I will tick it. THanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.var.html) `var` has `ddof` of `1` by default, [numpy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html) has it at `0`.

The get the same `var` in pandas as you're getting in numpy do

```
catDf.iloc[:,1:-1].var(ddof=0)
```

This comes down to the difference between [population variance and sample variance](http://www.differencebetween.net/science/mathematics-statistics/difference-between-sample-variance-population-variance/).

Note the sklearn [standard scaler](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) explicitly mention they use a ddof of 0 and that as it is unlikely to affect model performance (as it is just for scaling), they haven't exposed it as a configurable parameter.